# Just want checkbox value to pass to jquery variable

Tags: jquery

Input

```
<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox_to_update' name='checkbox_to_update' value='1'>
```

Want to pass value to jquery variable

Checkbox is checked

Tried `var checkbox_to_update = $("input[name='checkbox_to_update']");`

With alert get `[object Object]`

Then tried `var checkbox_to_update = $("#id").attr("checkbox_to_update");`

With alert get `undefined`

What is correct code for `var checkbox_to_update ='

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var checkbox_to_update = $("#checkbox_to_update").val();
```

Better is here to use ID as selector.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("input[id='checkbox_to_update']").is(':checked');
```

if Checkbox checked then it returns **true** else **false**

Answer (score 1):

Like this using id:

```
var checkbox_to_update = $("#checkbox_to_update").val();
```

or using name :

```
var checkbox_to_update = $("input[name='checkbox_to_update']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/68vjL/2/), this will help you

JS

```
var checkbox_to_update =$("#checkbox_to_update").prop('checked');
alert(checkbox_to_update);
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/68vjL/2/)

Comment: Try new fiddle it is change from old